# How to check if my monitor isn't compatible with my video card?

Tags: graphics-card, display, external-display

So I have an old monitor, a [DELL P1913s](https://www.cnet.com/products/dell-professional-p1913s-led-monitor-19-series/) and recently bought a new unit with a RX 560 video card.

My monitor works with my macbook pro 2015, and it also worked on the RX 560... not for long.

PC is booted, but no display after a restart. I am using a DVI-D in the monitor and HDMI in the video card. When I switch it to Mac, it works again. But when I plug it in the PC, it doesn't.

Is there any hardware incompatibility between the two? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried installing the latest drivers?

Comment: I did, @Aardwolf. Also, is it possible that my cable is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting your gpu and using the onboard graphics?

Comment: Yeah @Aardwolf that was my last test, I got it working and then I plugged in the gpu again and it works.. then after some time monitor lost signal again

Comment: Are you using the same cable when connecting to the Mac?

Comment: @Aardwolf Yes and I'm getting black and white noise monitor frequently

Comment: Is the GPU additionally powered from the motherboard?  Is that hooked up?  I can see the mac not actually using enough of the advanced features of the card to tax it.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas sorry, the GPU isn't connected to the Mac. It's on my PC. What I mean is when I plug the cable to my Mac, I get an output but when I plug it in my GPU in my PC, I'm not getting any. I have to keep restarting my PC to get an output

Comment: I get that.. ok.. does this card have additional power connectors?  I assume that it does.  Are they hooked up?  Is your power supply big enough to support it?  I am betting that there is NOTHING wrong with the monitor.

Comment: It is hooked up in the mobo but it has not additional power connectors.

Comment: The [DELL P1913s](https://www.dell.com/ae/business/p/dell-p1913/pd) seems to have a DisplayPort connection that you should be able to connect to the RX 560 DisplayPort